# How to do round trip yaml while preserving tags without defining constructors

Tags: python, formatting, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm trying to format YAML code without modifying comments, anchors and tags (basically take arbitrary YAML code and force particular indentation and other formatting conventions). To do this, I'm using ruamel.yaml 0.15.0 with the round trip feature (pretty much this example verbatim https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html).

Everything is working as expected, but the dump function is trying to resolve tags.  I can't seem to find anything on how to actually dump while preserving tags and not trying to load them. I'd rather not have to define constructors for these tags. Anyone know of any way to do this?

Here's a bare bones example:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
- &predef
  b: 42
- !sometag
  a: "with superfluous quotes"   # and with comment
  b: *predef
  c: |
     literal
     block style
     scalar
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

yaml_str2 = """\
# example
name: &hey
  # details
  family: !the_tag Smith   # very common
  given: Alice    # one of the siblings
name2: *hey
"""
data2 = yaml.load(yaml_str2)
yaml.dump(data2, sys.stdout)
```

The weird thing is that the first example works and the second one doesnt! What gives? Here's the error I'm getting:

```
- &predef
  b: 42
- !!sometag
  a: "with superfluous quotes"   # and with comment
  b: *predef
  c: |
    literal
    block style
    scalar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "format_yaml.py", line 31, in <module>
    data2 = yaml.load(yaml_str2)
  File "/opt/bb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 252, in load
    return constructor.get_single_data()
  File "/opt/bb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 102, in get_single_data
    return self.construct_document(node)
  File "/opt/bb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 112, in construct_document
    for dummy in generator:
  File "/opt/bb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 1279, in construct_yaml_map
    self.construct_mapping(node, data)
  File "/opt/bb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 1187, in construct_mapping
    value = self.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)
  File "/opt/bb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 162, in construct_object
    data = next(generator)  # type: ignore
  File "/opt/bb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 1359, in construct_undefined
    node.start_mark)
ruamel.yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag '!the_tag'
  in "<byte string>", line 4, column 11:
      family: !the_tag Smith   # very common
              ^ (line: 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade to the latest 0.15.X version, and check if you
**use the right instantiation of `YAML()` (without `typ='safe'`)**,
and then use its `.load()` and `.dump()` methods:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml


yaml_str = """\
# example
name: &hey
  # details
  family: !the_tag Smith   # very common
  given: Alice    # one of the siblings
name2: *hey
"""


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data['name']['given'] = 'Bob'
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
# example
name: &hey
  # details
  family: !the_tag Smith   # very common
  given: Bob      # one of the siblings
name2: *hey
```

Comment: The `RoundTripLoader` which you get when you don't specify the `typ` argument (or do `typ='rt'`) is a subclass of the `SafeLoader`. At no point the resolver tries to instantiate a `!the_tag` instance.

Comment: This example doesn't work! Very strange. I changed the main post to reflect it

Comment: Did you upgrade your version of ruamel.yaml, as instructed to do? You should be getting 0.15.60. The first one doesn't dump correct: I get `!sometag` and you get `!!sometag` in the output. That error was fixed since 0.15.0 and support for tags on scalars added as well.

Comment: Ah, i see. I'll check to see what version we're on.